# filesize is not working in IE 8 and 9

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Below is my code.

```
$("#aspNetForm").validate({
            rules: {
                txtManufacturerName: {
                    required: true
                },
                ddlStatus: {
                    selectstatus: true
                },
                file:
                                {
                                    requiredOnAdd: true,
                                    accept: 'jpg|gif|png|jpeg',
                                    filesize: 3145728
                                }
            },
            messages: {
                txtManufacturerName: {
                    required: "Kindly Enter  Name"
                },
                file: {
                    filesize: "Kindly Upload less than 3MB "
                }
            },
            onsubmit: false
        });
```

While inserting this record page doesn't fire the validation for `filesize`.
Please let me know how to do it?
I am using MVC3 C#

Comment: Filesize will not work in IE 8 and IE 9, because of their architecture. You can't check filesize in this browsers on client.

Answer (score 3):

IE8 and 9 do not support the HTML5 File API allowing to retrieve the file size using javascript which is the reason why this code doesn't work. This works only on browsers that support this.

You should always perform the validation on the server and browsers that support this function will be able to perform the validation on the client as well. Unfortunately IE8 and 9 are not part of those browsers.